# Is it possible to let sourcetree or any other git GUI work for a git worktree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-worktree

For example, If I have created a A repo (home/user/A_dir) by “git init”, there is a .git (/home/user/A_dir/.git) then when I open the A_dir in sourcetree it works well.

Next I create a worktree using `git worktree add --checkout /home/user/B_dir <branch_name>` , when I open the B_dir in smartgit it says “git status failed with code 128: not a git repository: /home/user/A_dir/.git/worktrees/A1” and I found in B_dir there is no .git folder, there is only .git file “gitfile:/home/user/A_dir/.git/worktrees/A1”

Is it possbile that make the sourcetree work on B_dir?

Comment: Any decent gui (or IDE) should be able to support worktrees out of the box.... it's not like a hidden git feature. I guess a big question is whether `libgit2` supports them, given that a lot of clients are based on it (and I don't know how support is there, by the way).

Comment: I tried sourcetree and slickedit, both reported "not a git repository", but seems vscode gitLen support it

Comment: It seems that indeed Sourcetree **for Windows** doesn't support worktrees (maybe because relying on libgit2 and so it needs a specific support). But when the GUI is relying on the git exe, there is in fact no extra dev needed. The git process is doing he heavy lifting. I can assure you as https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions was always able to open worktrees (and I am the one that have added the worktree management in it )

Comment: yes, the tool is cool and I like it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason. The reason is I mount a remote server's folder into local and the repo is on the mounted disk. So the content in the gitfile is not the same with the one it should be on the remote server. If I change the path of the gitfile designate, all the tools works well